# Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock

Tags: 14.04

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I've done everything i could and i still get this can anyone help?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1131075/edit) your question and tell us what everything is that you have tried.  All we can do is guess at what you have done from here so we might be giving you steps that you have already tried.

Comment: I suspect you have tried to run a command without `sudo` (which raises your privileges).  This however is assumption, which is why @Terrance asked for you to provide your command & thus avoid this *guessing*

Comment: Apart from your question, 14.04 will be EOL in 2 weeks. Consider upgrading to a newer Ubuntu version.